# Correctly indexing multiple domains with same content in Google and others

Tags: google, search-engines, seo, multiple-domains

I have a client with a dozen territorial domains, like mydomain.co.uk, mydomain.fr, mydomain.de, etc Most of these domains hold a different language of the same dynamic content (shop), but some, like co.uk and .com, have the same language and content, except for some content customized to each country/domain in the front page, contact and other pages.

I am aware that we should use the canonical meta tag to mark those duplicated contents, but, we want the co.uk to be present in UK ( indexed in google.co.uk ) and the .com to be present in US and other countries, for example, or least that is the goal.

Is there anything we can do to "help" google determine the geographical meaning of each domain? If we mark with canonical tag the .com and co.uk sites, do you know how google will decide which one to show on a given search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Google Webmasters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) tools to specify the domain of the .com or .co.uk, to be sure that google understand where the domain is.

By default .co.uk -> UK , but for the .com you can specify it under "Site Configuration" -> "Settings"

Comment: Thanks! Another little tip is to specify in your pages the language of the content, specify en_US and en_UK as page-language via meta-tags!

Comment: Yes, good point, I didn't remember that one either!