# Multiple domain names and with same content. In different language and same

Tags: multiple-domains, top-level-domains, internationalization, language, international

I have multiple domain names with same content. Some with a different language and some with the same. I have a main website with a hotel name that has been around for some years now. I have recently bought websites with a better name related to area.

I don't want to change the main site as it would disrupt business and its doing OK anyway, but I do want to target certain countries better with the new domains with the new TLDs.

I will be using the same content and 2 domains the same language uk & USA. How do I tell google that this is the same website although the domain names are quite different from the original domain?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters SE! I think your question is very similar to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/9954/78243). If the answer given there doesn't help you, please edit your question and tell us why not.